# How to return expected value from within another function in Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase

I have a function that returns a boolean to check if a user already voted on post. However, I'm struggling to get the correct boolean to return. I run a Firebase query to check the data in the backend but the defaul boolean of false is always returned. What's the best way to sort this logic out?

I understand why it's defaulting to false: I set it above the block, and then the code hits the `return false` before the query can complete. What's the best approach?

```
func didAlreadyVote(message: MessageType) -> Bool {

    // check user votes collection to see if current message matches
    guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else {return false}
    let userID = currentUser.uid
    var bool = false
    let docRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(userID).collection("upvotes").whereField("messageId", isEqualTo: message.messageId)

    docRef.getDocuments { querySnapshot, error in

        if let error = error {
            print("Error getting documents: \(error)")
            bool = false
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                bool = true
            }
        }
    }
    return bool
}
```

Comment: Completion blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning before the closure got a chance to complete, hence, the return value is `false`. To solve this, you can pass another closure in the function signature:

```
func didAlreadyVote(message: MessageType, completion: (Bool) -> Void) {

    // check user votes collection to see if current message matches
    guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else {return false}
    let userID = currentUser.uid
    let docRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(userID).collection("upvotes").whereField("messageId", isEqualTo: message.messageId)

    docRef.getDocuments { querySnapshot, error in

        if let error = error {
            print("Error getting documents: \(error)")
            completion(false)
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                completion(true) /// Note that this will get called multiple times if you have more the one document!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
didAlreadyVote(message: messageType) { didVote in
        // didVote is the value returned
}
```

Comment: thanks! How can I call this function? I tried `var bool = didAlreadyVote(message: message, completion: (Bool) -> Void)` but it returns error `Cannot convert value of type '((Bool) -> Void).Type' to expected argument type '(Bool) -> Void'`

Comment: @winston I updated my answer, hope this helps!

Comment: thanks again, unfortunately Xcode is making this really difficult! It made me change to `didAlreadyVote(message: MessageType.self as! MessageType)`, then the code crashes right at that line: `Could not cast value of type 'MessageKit.MessageType.Protocol' (0x10dad4b10) to 'MessageKit.MessageType' (0x10dacd3d8)`. UGH. How can I just tell XCode I want `message: MessageType` and not the protocol?

Comment: can I just set a variable to equal the result of the function? Like `var bool = didAlreadyVote`

Comment: The function expected an element of type MessageType, not a Type. Pass in one of the MessageType values. `MessageType.self as! MessageType` this will crash. @winston